# How can I list what zfs compression algorithms are available?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux, openzfs

I have a zfs pool on a production system and I would like to see if it's possible to use zstd compression instead of the current gzip setting.

Is there any way to list available compression options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: Simply running `zfs get` will show the available options.
In my case, the answer is no - zstd is not available:

```
# zfs get
missing property argument
usage:
        get [-rHp] [-d max] [-o "all" | field[,...]]
            [-t type[,...]] [-s source[,...]]
            <"all" | property[,...]> [filesystem|volume|snapshot|bookmark] ...

The following properties are supported:

        PROPERTY       EDIT  INHERIT   VALUES
    enter code here
[...]
compression     YES      YES   on | off | lzjb | gzip | gzip-[1-9] | zle | lz4
[...]
```

Comment: In your situation, you should consider lz4 if zstd is unavailable.

Comment: @ewwhite no because I need a high compression ratio more than speed. I just need to upgrade zfs 